# Cam sprocket pin!

Tags: troubleshooting, malibu, timing-chain

During timing chain replacement on my 2011 Malibu 4-cylinder engine, I noticed that the alignment dowel pin on the exhaust cam sprocket came off but it is still in the hole in the camshaft gear(so it is not broken or sheared off, just in the cam shaft hole where it is supposed to be after installation) I put the chain on the sprockets and the marks on the chain are aligned perfectly with the marks on the gears. I pushed the exhaust cam sprocket into the camshaft gear and it looks like it is flush with the end of the camshaft. I tightened the the cam sprocket bolts and rotated the crank shaft to make sure everything is moving smoothly, and everything is moving correctly and lined up. The question is: should I have removed the pin from the camshaft and put it back on the sprocket before I did everything else? Like I stated earlier, everything seems to be in order the way it is with no apprent problems and I think the pin is aligned perfectly on both ends with no wobble. Please let me know before I put everything back together! Thank you for your time

Comment: Is the dowel part way into the cam shaft and part way into the sprocket as it should be?

Comment: I can’t really see it, but I can tell that it is in place correctly because the sprocket moves around with ease without wobble. In previous attempts to set it correctly, it looked like it was lined up but upon rotating the engine it was hard to rotate and the sprocket had a wobble and the pin was out of alignment.